# SQL-like Inner Join for Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const products = [{
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
  }
];

const cart = [{
  id: 101,
  userId: 3,
  productId: 5,
  quantity: 2
}];

totals = cart.reduce((r, {
      productId: id,
      quantity
    }) =>
    (r[id] = (r[id] || 0) + quantity, r), {}),
  result = products.map(({
    id,
    productName,
    unitprice
  }) => ({
    productName,
    unitprice,
    quantity: totals[id]
  }));

console.log(result)
```

Currently, it prints two rows instead of one row. Second row should not be printed because there is only one row in `cart`. How do I the so-called inner join which return only one record which is for cart id 101?

Comment: You're using map and it is supposed to return the same number of element as in the array you're operating on

Comment: Did you even try to adjust the code? Where is the content of `result` coming from? Think about why `.map()` might not be the best option. Check the prototype of `Array` for better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want retain the cart with the "join", you can map the found product (without its id) and include the quantity.

```js
const products = [{
  id: 5,
  productName: "Logitech Mouse",
  unitprice: 35
}, {
  id: 6,
  productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
  unitprice: 40
}];

const cart = [{
  id: 101,
  userId: 3,
  productId: 5,
  quantity: 2
}];

let joined = cart.map(item => {
  let { id, ...rest} = products.find(p => p.id === item.productId);
  return { ...rest, 'quantity' : item.quantity };
});

console.log(joined);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

If you want the total price of all items in the cart you will need to:

1. Reduce the cart by the items within it
2. Locate the product by its id
3. Add to the total, the unit price of the product times the quantity in the cart

```js
const products = [{
  id: 5,
  productName: "Logitech Mouse",
  unitprice: 35
}, {
  id: 6,
  productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
  unitprice: 40
}];

const cart = [{
  id: 101,
  userId: 3,
  productId: 5,
  quantity: 2
}];

let total = cart.reduce((subtotal, item) => {
  let product = products.find(p => p.id === item.productId);
  return subtotal + product.unitprice * item.quantity;
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Short version:

```js
let t = cart.reduce((s, i) => s + products.find(p => p.id === i.productId).unitprice * i.quantity, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `map` function like this

```js
const products = [{
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
},
{
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
}
];

const cart = [{
    id: 101,
    userId: 3,
    productId: 5,
    quantity: 2
}];

result = cart.map(item => {
    const product = products.find(product => item.productId === product.id);
    return { id: item.id, quantity: item.quantity, productName: product.productName, unitprice: product.unitprice }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

While Mr. Polywhirl's answer is a cleaner and better solution, here is a simple edit to your code that solves your problem. The reason why your code returns two is because of the `map`. Replace it with `filter` and the condition on the presence of `id` to solve the issue.

```js
const products = [{
        id: 5,
        productName: "Logitech Mouse",
        unitprice: 35
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
        unitprice: 40
    }
];

const cart = [{
    id: 101,
    userId: 3,
    productId: 5,
    quantity: 2
}];

totals = cart.reduce((r, {
            productId: id,
            quantity
        }) =>
        (r[id] = (r[id] || 0) + quantity, r), {}),
    result = products.filter(({
        id,
        productName,
        unitprice
    }) => {
        if (totals[id]) return ({
            productName,
            unitprice,
            quantity: totals[id]
        })
    });

console.log(result)
```